# Data in React Not Saving

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to save the data in price and return it in the end of a function. That way I can call on the function in a different file to fetch price data and save it elsewhere. When I print the price inside of the 2nd `.then(function(...))` , it gives me the correct current price, but at the end of the whole function, it prints 0. The return statement inside of the `.then` isnt returning the parsed float either. How do I get the data to save and return?

```
export function FetchStockPrice (ticker) {

function stockPrice() {
    const API_KEY = '###';
    let StockSymbol = ticker;
    let API_CALL = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=' + StockSymbol + '&interval=5min&apikey=${API_KEY}';
    let price = 0;

    fetch(API_CALL)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function(data) { 
                // console.log("data" + data)
                price = (parseFloat(data["Time Series (5min)"][Object.keys(data['Time Series (5min)'])[0]]["4. close"]));
                console.log(price);
                return parseFloat(data["Time Series (5min)"][Object.keys(data['Time Series (5min)'])[0]]["4. close"]);
                //console.log(data[Object.keys(data)[1]]);
                
                // console.log(d);
                // return parseFloat(d);
            }
        )
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })
}

thePrice = stockPrice();
return thePrice;
```

}

Comment: since getting data is an asynchronous operation, you cannot just return it from the function. You can use async-await, but this will mean that the stockPrice function will return a promise, and you'll have to use `then` or `await` for it as well.

Comment: ☝ and yes you should be returning the `fetch` as `return fetch(....)` from your function and get the data as `stockPrice().then(data=>data)` this `data` would be the value you may want

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, You should return a fetch call and use `async await` in other file to catch the data you want since it will return a promise.

```js
export function fetchStockPrice(ticker) {

  function callAPI(url) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        return parseFloat(
          data["Time Series (5min)"][
            Object.keys(data["Time Series (5min)"])[0]
          ]["4. close"]
        );
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("error", e);
      });
  }

  async function stockPrice() {
    const API_KEY = "apiKey";
    let API_CALL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=${API_KEY}`;

    return await callAPI(API_CALL).then((res) => res);
  }

  return stockPrice();
}
```

```js
// other file 

import { fetchStockPrice } from "./fetchStockPrice";

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      console.log(await fetchStockPrice());
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I can't use useEffect in the other file as it is a class that extends React.component. Is there another way to call FetchStockPrice and save it in the state of the other component?